# What is DynamoDB max througput for 1 item?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Let’s assume I create a DynamoDB table (on demand to avoid throttling).
Let’s then assume I insert only 1 item in this table (the size of the item is 400KB).

If I want to read this item, I will use the GetItem call.

One read in that case will consume 100 RCUs (consistent read only in my example).

Hence is it correct to say I will only be able to read the item 30 times per second ?

Why 30 ? Because, the max RCU of a partition is 3000 and in this example it is impossible to split the partition since there is only 1 item.
Maybe this example sounds absurd but could you confirm me this is correct and it is a hard limit of DynamoDB ?

Thank you

Comment: I think you mean 100 RCUs, not 100 WCUs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is correct. It's a hard limit or 3000RCU and 1000WCU.

Why you ask, as it's shared hardware this was the happy medium we found that prevented "noisy neighbors" from impacting other users. That's also the reason it's a hard limit.

If you need more than 3000RCU per item then consider serving from a cache like DAX.